# Updating SDE point feature classes with SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: arcmap, c#, point, sql-server, arcgis-runtime

I am contacting you in hope that you can help me resolve an issue using SQL Server 2008 R2 to push updates to a SDE point feature class.

We are using a C# app that uses ArcGIS Runtime to edit the attribute table and create new address records with their cooresponding points.   The problem is we can see the updates in ArcMap, the new records are showing up, and when you click on the record the place where the point should be is highlighted, however it doesn't graphically display the point in ArcMap.

I have been working with ESRI and they can't seem to figure out the problem.  So I thought I would reach out and see if you have any suggestions.

Comment: you don't have enough information here in my opinion. what does the code look like in your c# app to save the point?